# DHCP Server & Client

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

So I'm having a bit of trouble getting my DHCP server to assign and IP address to my clients. I have the dhcpd.conf file configured to assign a range of IP address to my clients as follows:

```
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 192.168.0.255;
option routers 192.168.0.254;
option domain-name-servers "tindo.com";
option domain-name "ns.tindo.com";

subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  interface eth1;
  range 192.168.0.103 192.168.0.110;
}
```

Between a few examples that I've seen, some people have put the "options" within the subnet part of the code. I'm not sure if that matters or not.

On my client, I have its network interface file configured as follows:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

After I have configured the dhcpd.conf file, I tried to start the DHCP server with the command

```
sudo service isc-dhcp-server start
```

However, when I do, it says that the job failed to start.

Any know what may be causing this? This is my first time trying to run a DHCP server, so I get the feeling that I'm over looking something. Thank you for your time.

Comment: could you perhaps run it verbosely? I think there's a command line utility dhcpd and then you can probably add option -f to keep it in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add interface in `sudo nano /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server` which will be used for dhcp req and answare.

```
#Defaults for dhcp initscript
#sourced by /etc/init.d/dhcp
#installed at /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server by the maintainer scripts
#
#This is a POSIX shell fragment
#
#On what interfaces should the DHCP server (dhcpd) serve DHCP requests"
#Separate multiple interfaces with spaces, e.g. “eth0 eth1".
INTERFACES="eth0"
```

Replace eth0 above with the name of your network interface that you want the server to lease addresses on.